# DATE - date + days HANA

Tags: hana

I have a 1 column with date example 2016-10-05 and 2 column I have number of days (number of days is always different like 14,16, 18). In my column 3 I would like get result. Date+number of days. 
I tried

`SELECT ADD_DAYS (TO_DATE ('2009-12-05', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 30) "add days" FROM DUMMY;`

but I have always diffrent number not 30 like in example.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just plug the column names into the ADD_DAYS function.

```
SELECT ADD_DAYS (TO_DATE ("COL_1", 'YYYY-MM-DD'), "COL_2") "add days" FROM table;
```